# What is the best way to read A Dance with Dragons and A Feast for Crows?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, suggested-order

The two books occur during the same time frame, but in different locations. My first read-through was in [rough chronological order according to boiledleather.com](http://boiledleather.com/post/25902554148/a-new-readerfriendly-combined-reading-order-for-a).

I am planning to reread the series in anticipation for "The Winds of Winter", and was wondering if anyone read the books in a different order that they particularly enjoyed? I've considered reading all of the chapters for each character in chronological order, has anyone tried that? Or possibly have a better suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is to simply read them in the order of release, as the author intended.

Comment: Well, grrm first wrote these two books as a single volume. It got too large, and he was forced to split them.

Comment: Agreed, but he still decided the order and split it up in a way that made the most sense to him.

Comment: True, but it still wasn't his first choice. If he had his druthers, it would all be a single volume, right?

Comment: @DanBurden Perhaps not. *He* was the one who made the story so large; `it [the story] grew in the telling` was his own doing. He couldn't possibly have expected people to read such a large book with ease; hence the split.

Comment: @DanBurden To be sure though, he's made it so that you don't miss a thing and it's definitely not confusing to read them in order of release. Besides, he has famously said and given cavils about chronology, both within and outside of the books. Namely that things don't necessarily run in tandem. This is the case even in the other books which weren't split. The key here is that no matter *how* you read the books, just pay enough attention that you don't miss the small things!

Comment: On a separate note, many people have read and re-read the books multiple times, you could try all of the methods :p

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [a combined chapter order](http://boiledleather.com/post/24543217702/a-proposed-a-feast-for-crowsa-dance-with-dragons).

This is a roughly chronological order of the chapters that I used in my re-read (technically a re-listen) of the two books. It makes for a much smoother reread, and even makes sense given that the two were originally going to be one book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I did the exact list in my first read-through (see original post).